# Fluch cache on all sites in multisite platform

Tags: drush, multi-sites, aegir

Is there a way to clear cache on all sites in platform by using platform alias? For example, `drush @platform_name cc all` ? (its multisite setup via aegir).

The problem I am facing with is, when I run that command or the one with @sites, I get a message

> Could not find a Drupal settings.php file at sites/default/settings.php.

So, I then copied default.settings.php as settings.php (which is by default fully commented out) in sites/default, and then it says

> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

Which is obvious, as default doesn't have database (Aegir creates all sites in platform as separately and never touches default).

I also tried to delete default folder but Drush is telling me it needs to have settings.php there (even after I cleared drush cache). Drush in question is 8.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is via the views bulk operations.
When you select some or all sites you can expand the operations menu at the top, where you should find 'Site: Flush_cache'. It's part of the hosting_tasks_extra module (which is included by default now)

Note that you currently do have to enable the operation in the sites view. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2715945